# Magento 2 : Cart page total block messed up in AWS server

Tags: magento2, totals

I have one query. I have 2 copy of one site one is in AWS server and another one is in Site ground. In site ground all works fine but in AWS it will messed up total block in cart page.

[image]

Comment: Please add more detail.

Comment: Can you please tell me what details you need? @AbhishekPanchal

Comment: Since when it got messed up? did you recently move your DB and source  on AWS? and how?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal yes when I add to cart product and go to cart page at that time it will look something like this. Yes we move database recently.

Comment: did you try running all those commands like `static:content:deploy`, indexer and cache?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal Yes I done these all commands.

Comment: Please check screen shot. http://prntscr.com/ix2dn4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75144/discussion-between-mayur-and-abhishek-panchal).